# thrust functor: "too many resources requested for launch"

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm trying to implement something like this in CUDA:

for each element

```
p = { p if p >= floor
      z if p < floor
```

Where `floor` and `z` are constants configured at the start of the test.

I have attempted to implement it like so, but I get the error "too many resources requested for launch"

A functor:

```
struct floor_functor : thrust::unary_function <float, float>
{
        const float floorLevel, floorVal;

        floor_functor(float _floorLevel, float _floorVal) : floorLevel(_floorLevel), floorVal(_floorVal){}

        __host__
        __device__
        float operator()(float& x) const
        {
            if (x >= floorLevel)
                return x;
            else
                return floorVal;
        }
};
```

Used by a transform:

```
thrust::transform(input->begin(), input->end(), output.begin(), floor_functor(floorLevel, floorVal));
```

If I remove one of the members of my functor, say `floorVal`, and use a functor with only one member variable, it works fine.

Does anyone know why this might be, and how I could fix it?

**Additional info:**

My array is 786432 elements long.

My GPU is a GeForce GTX590

I am building with the command:

```
`nvcc -c -g -arch sm_11 -Xcompiler -fPIC -Xcompiler -Wall -DTHRUST_DEBUG  -I <my_include_dir> -o <my_output> <my_source>`
```

My cuda version is 4.0:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2011 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_May_12_11:09:45_PDT_2011
Cuda compilation tools, release 4.0, V0.2.1221
```

And my maximum number of threads per block is 1024 (reported by deviceQuery):

```
Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    1024 x 1024 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     65535 x 65535 x 65535
```

**UPDATE::**

I have stumbled upon a fix for my problem, but do not understand it.  If I rename my functor from "floor_functor" to basically anything else, it works!  I have *no* idea why this is the case, and would be interested to hear anyone's ideas about this.

Comment: What GPU are you running this on, and what CUDA version are you using? It probably means that the thrust kernel launch is requesting too many threads per block for the number of registers your functor is using, but that is just a guess.

Comment: how many elements are in input?

Comment: In addition to the information that talonmies requested, what command line did you use to compile your code?

Comment: I think the first comment is most relevant, and the additions you gave don't show us your thread/block launch configuration. Have you checked what the maximum threads per block are for your machine?

Comment: I'm using a thrust transform, so the thread/block configuration is not controlled by me.  I'm not aware of any way to change it either.  If that is the problem, perhaps it's a bug in thrust?

Comment: You could determine if it is running out of registers by adding `-maxrregcount=20` (or less) to the command line.

Comment: BTW, I think technically you want your prototype to be `float operator()(const float& x) const`.

Comment: @EMS: Thrust doesn't expose kernel execution parameters to the caller, it automagically determines them at runtime using internal functions and the API

Comment: @jatoo: I think you should try compiling with `arch=sm_20` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  @harrism:  I tried `maxrregcount=20` and also 10, but no difference.
@talonmies: `arch=sm_20` didn't seem to help either.

Comment: Can you try CUDA 4.1 to see if that fixes it?

Answer (score 1):

For an easier CUDA implementation, you could do this with ArrayFire in one line of code:

```
p(p < floor) = z;
```

Just declare your variables as af::array's.

Good luck!

Disclaimer: I work on all sorts of CUDA projects, including ArrayFire.